# Change default behaviour of Angular Material Design <mat-select>

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hey guys I do have a simple `<mat-select>` form where users could choose between three options. If the user has selected an option and presses the enter key the search button should be triggered. So far everything works fine with that code below:

```
<mat-input-container>
 <mat-select onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
    document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();>
  <mat-option>
   Option 1
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
   Option 2
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
   Option 3
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-input-container>
<button mat-button id="btnSearch" (click)="search()">Search</button>
```

Now here is my problem:
If the user has chosen one option and presses the enter key the `<mat-select>` form expands and all options are shown again. Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

I tried to add something like `$event.stopPropagation();` to the onkeydown event but it didn´t work out.

I found pretty similar question here [Is there a way to change this Angular 4+ Material Design Mat-Select default behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739799/is-there-a-way-to-change-this-angular-4-material-design-mat-select-default-beha)
But It didn´t solve my problem

Anybody who could help? Best regards

Comment: Why don't you use the angular event emiter like this `(keypress)="$event.keyCode === 13 && search()"` ?
You can add the decorator `ViewChild` of your `mat-select` and then use the `this.mySelect.close` in the search method.

Answer (score 1):

Hints for starters : you can replace this

```
<mat-select 
  onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();>
```

With this :

```
<mat-select (keyup.enter)="document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();>
```

This is how you detect an enter key in Angular.

Furtermore, since you are using Angular, you have access to local variables. this means you can (but more importantly, you should) do this :

```
<mat-select (keyup.enter)="search.click();>
<button #search mat-button id="btnSearch" (click)="search()">Search</button>
```

Now, about your issue, I also faced it and never have been able to resolve it. What you should do, however, is open an issue on their Github repository, and ask for a way to prevent the options expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to prevent expanding of drop-down option on Enter-Key press once it is selected. I was having same issue and i fixed this using below code in `mat-select`.

```
<mat-select
(keydown.enter)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();" >
```

With reference to your code instead of using

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13)
    document.getElementById('btnSearch').click(); this in `mat-select`.
```

Use as below code.

```
<mat-input-container>
 <mat-select (keydown.enter)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();">
  <mat-option>
   Option 1
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
   Option 2
  </mat-option>
  <mat-option>
   Option 3
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-input-container>
<button mat-button id="btnSearch" (click)="search()">Search</button>
```